# Cache miss under heavy load in memcached

Tags: php, memcached, load-testing

I'm using memcached with php 5.2. Last week, we load tested our site and a weird issue happened. I have a particular key which is accessed a number of times (say 10-15) in a request. It always results in a hit under normal site load.

When we increased the load, it suddenly started missing (For an 8 CPU machine, under an average load of around 30). It happens every time the load is increased and stops when load resumes to normal and it happens only for this key.

Has anyone else experienced this issue before? Is there a work around?

Thanks

Comment: Increase amount of memory provided for memcache (in its config). Amount of CPU/cores doens't matter in this case.

Comment: Amount of memory is not the issue. There is more than 50% free.

Comment: I'm speaking about amount of memory provided for memcache. As opposed to other programs, memcache will not use as much memory as it could. Are you speaking about 50% from total server memory or relative to defined cache size?

Comment: I'm speaking about the memory assigned to memcached. We have assigned 1GB total and it's using ~500MB.

Comment: Well... this could be weird app architecture (review it), fast cache invalidation (increase cache timeout for this entry) or "cache miss storm" - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/09/10/cache-miss-storm/

Answer (score 1):

memcached works 'kinda' like a LRU list, but then kinda not: **Checkout memcached for dummies** : http://work.tinou.com/2011/04/memcached-for-dummies.html

What strikes me as alarming is how many times you access memcached per request... for the same item? You might want to reduce this "chatter" by "request caching" these look-ups.